# How to remove files from Eclipse IDE File Search

Tags: eclipse

I want to remove all the .png files from Eclipse IDE File Search (and not have to do this every time I use the function). How can I do this?

It is searching my Workspace.  I've tried excluding these files from the Project (using Project - Properties - Resource Filters), but that has not changed the search.

I'm using Eclipse 4.6.0.

Comment: I was able to do this in my old version of Eclipse. I think I had the files excluded from the project.  But now that method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.

Just go to Eclipse->File search->In the file name pattern text box
exclude the type of files you want to search without like
!x=*.png,*.jpg.

Hope it helps.

cheers,

Saurav